# Как сделать токен на ERC20 кросчейн из Arbitrum?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Нужно разработать кросчейн токен в сетях Ethereum и Arbitrum. Сам контракт для создания токена на ERC20 я написал, это не проблема, а как сделать его кросчейн из Arbitrum, это вопрос, Бросьте пожалуйста какую-нибудь документацию или дайте совет
КОД ТОКЕНУ

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.1/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.1/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.1/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.1/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.1/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Permit.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.1/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Votes.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.1/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20FlashMint.sol";

contract GTA is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, ERC20Pausable, AccessControl, ERC20Permit, ERC20Votes, ERC20FlashMint {
    bytes32 public constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");

    constructor(address defaultAdmin, address pauser, address minter)
        ERC20("Teramux", "TRM")
        ERC20Permit("TRM")
    {
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, defaultAdmin);
        _grantRole(PAUSER_ROLE, pauser);
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10 ** decimals());
        _grantRole(MINTER_ROLE, minter);
    }

    function pause() public onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
        _unpause();
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _update(address from, address to, uint256 value)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Pausable, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._update(from, to, value);
    }

    function nonces(address owner)
        public
        view
        override(ERC20Permit, Nonces)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.nonces(owner);
    }

    
}
```